# Get user position on the viewport

Tags: geometry

I'm creating a game, and I want to get the user x and y position on the viewport, but the problem is, I only have the world size and the viewport size and the user position based on the world.
I made an image to illustrate better what I mean: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah8QQ.png)

The world is: 3809x3809

The viewport is: 778x667

The user is: 50x50 and his position based on the world is: 800x600

I want to know how to get the user x and y based on the viewport.

Comment: Yo need to know the position of the viewport.

Comment: Is it possible without knowing the viewport position?

Comment: No, it's obviously impossible. You must know the world position of one vertex of the viewport.